# What is a gender-neutral word(s) for the word "maternity"?

Tags: single-word-requests, gender-neutral, political-correctness, sexual-minorities

The word *maternity* as in the sentence "the maternity wear is over there. If you'd like to follow me..." is typically the go-to language when describing, talking with, or about pregnant persons' wear, but this is *not* inclusive towards [people who are not women and or cis who can get pregnant](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Transgender_pregnancy) (e.g. trans men).

So, what is a word(s) that is operatively gender-neutral and which can replace the term *maternity*?

We have the word *parental* to replace the word *maternal* to describe a person who is not a woman who is parenting a child, for example, but what about the word about which I am asking?

Comment: Comments are not for extended discussion; this conversation has been [moved to chat](https://chat.stackexchange.com/rooms/106928/discussion-on-question-by-english-learner-what-is-a-gender-neutral-words-for-t).

Answer (score 4, accepted):

The clear and obvious choice would be to call it *pregnancy wear* (worn while pregnant) or *nursing clothes* (worn to easily facilitate breastfeeding), as in these examples:

- [Maternity Clothes & Pregnancy Wear | JoJo Maman Bébé](https://www.jojomamanbebe.com/maternity-clothes.html)

  - > Beautiful maternity and nursing clothes and practical maternity products from JoJo Maman Bébé.
- [Maternity Clothes & Pregnancy Clothes | Motherhood Maternity](https://www.motherhood.com/maternity-clothes/)
- [Maternity Clothes | Pregnancy Clothing | boohoo](https://us.boohoo.com/maternity)
- [View All Nursing Wear - Milk & Baby](https://www.milkandbaby.com/collections/view-all-nursing)
- > See all of our breastfeeding tops, shirts, tanks, sweaters, and dresses made for breastfeeding.

(It's interesting to note that *maternity* is used as a keyword on many of these pages.)

In the case of “maternity leave”, the common term is “[new parent leave](https://www.in.gov/spd/2738.htm)”, which is a bit broader as it can cover anyone who is getting a child, such as the non-pregnant spouse or anyone adopting a child.